# Understanding what a statement means

Tags: graph-theory

I'm trying review for the finals by reading the text but I ran into an exercise with a sentence that I can't understand.

> Draw the network associated with the bipartite graph.

What does that really mean?  The graph provided is a bipartite graph with left hand side vertices a to e and right hand side vertices 1 to 9.  I don't see s nor t.  Can someone tell me what does the sentence mean, or trying to ask?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, we don't see $s$ or $t$ either, so we know how you feel.  (Please edit $s$ and $t$ into your question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only guess, but my guess is that you are supposed to add a source and a sink, and connect the former to the letter vertices, and the latter to the number vertices. You then direct the edges of the graph from source to sink. Just one man's opinion...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's what I thought as well, thanks!